# Is changing button color on a press in tkinter possible?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I’m using Python’s tkinter module and I want to change the color of a button only when it's getting pressed. So for an example normally the button would be white, but when I press it, it would turn green. If I stop pressing it, it would turn back to white. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Is that all you're asking? Have you tried doing it to see what would happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest method is to use the "activebackground" property of the button

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(root,text="click me",activebackground="red")
btn.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

This example will set the background color of the button to red when it is being pressed and return to it's original color when released.

In a similar way you get change the default background color.

```
btn = tk.Button(root,text="click me", background="white", activebackground="red")
```